# How to free memory allocated by thread-function in the main

Tags: c, memory-management, pthreads, free

I have allocated `heap` memory in the thread function `f1`, this storage is used to calculate the value in the heap region so that the main function can see it.

Here is the thread function definition:

```
void *f1(void *input){


        int sum = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        /* Do calculation */   
        pthread_exit((void*)&sum);
}
```

In the above code, the `sum` is the heap allocated storage, whose address is passed as a return value to the `sum1` in the `main()`.

I `join` the thread in the `main()` like this:

```
void *sum1;
pthread_join(tid1,(void**)&sum1);
```

Once i retrieved the value, i want to `free` the allocated memory.
When i use `free` in the main, it complains like `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`

How can i explicitly and safely `free` this memory ?

Comment: You wrote `int sum`, I guess a pointer is needed here.

Comment: @prog-fh. You are right, Its a typo error, let me correct this

Comment: Please do not fix those bugs in your code that are essential for asking the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send back the pointer, not its address

```
pthread_exit(sum);
...
pthread_join(tid1, &sum1);
```

From the thread function you want to send back (with `return` or `pthread_exit()`) a pointer.
At `pthread_join()` you want to obtain this pointer but the result of `pthread_join()` is an integer to report success/failure.
Then we have to declare a pointer variable (`sum1` here) to store the expected result and provide `pthread_join()` with the address of this variable so that it could be updated (the same way we provide addresses to `scanf()` in order to update the extracted variables).

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is the use of **casts**. In C most of the time a pointer cast signifies an **erroneous construct**. Notably in this example no casts are required if the constructs are used correctly:

```
// no cast required because malloc returns void * and void * can be converted
// to a pointer to int without a cast
int *sum = malloc(sizeof (int));

// no cast required because int * can be converted to a void * without a cast
pthread_exit(sum);

void *sum1;

// no cast required because the address of void * is a void **!
pthread_join(tid1, &sum1);
```

The only place where you require a cast is if you now convert this `void *` **value** to `int *` inline:

```
int value = *(int *)sum1;
```

but you can convert it by assignment too, and then again, no cast is required:

```
int *value_ptr = sum1;
printf("The value was %d\n", *value_ptr);
free(value_ptr);
```

The rule of thumb is that a cast is OK if you know something better than a compiler - like "truncate this value to `uint8_t`" or "this void pointer actually points to an `int`, but I am not assigning it to one to save keystrokes" - but it is usually not OK just to silence a warning.

---

Some programmers write code like this:

```
int *ptr;
pthread_join(tid1, (void **)&ptr);
```

Such code is not strictly conforming as an `int *` and `void *` are not compatible types, may have or not have the same representation or even size, and especially may not alias each other.